# How to dcast a dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe like following:

```
   extrovert       introvert      open
      1               2            2
      3               3            2
```

I want to convert it following format:

```
  extrovert1    extrovert2    extrovert3    introvert1   introvert2   introvert3    open1    open2    open3
      1             0            0             0             1            0           0       1        0  
      0             0            1             0             0            1           0       1        0
```

I am using following code to convert it to desired format

```
dcast(setDT(behavior_cluster), rowid() ~ extrovert,
      value.var = c("extrovert","introvert","open"))
```

But, it gives me an error. How can I do it in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) (which you are obviously using):

```
setDT(behavior_cluster)

DT <- melt(behavior_cluster[, ri := .I],
           measure.vars = 1:3, variable.factor = FALSE)

DT[, m := max(value), variable
   ][rep(1:nrow(DT), m)
     ][, value := +(value == rowid(ri, variable))
       ][, variable := paste0(variable,seq_along(variable)), by = .(rleid(ri))
         ][, dcast(.SD, ri ~ variable, value.var = 'value')][, ri := NULL][]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    extrovert1 extrovert2 extrovert3 introvert1 introvert2 introvert3 open1 open2
> 1:          1          0          0          0          1          0     0     1
> 2:          0          0          1          0          0          1     0     1
> ```

---

An alternative which also gets three columns in the result for `open`:

```
DT[rep(1:nrow(DT), max(value))
   ][, value := +(value == rowid(ri, variable))
     ][, variable := paste0(variable, 1:.N), by = .(ri, variable)
       ][, dcast(.SD, ri ~ variable, value.var = 'value')][, ri := NULL][]
```

Comment: I just want 1 and 0 for a non-zero value.